# Bayes estimator from Beta prior Geometric data

Tags: probability, statistics, bayesian

Let $X$ be random variable of geometric distribution $f_{\theta}(x)=(1-
\theta)\cdot \theta^x$ for $x=0,1,\dots .\;$

Find Bayes estimator of $
\theta$ calculated on a basis of observation $X=0$ which is $E(\Theta|X=0)$.

My problem is with a priori distribution which is $\pi(\theta)=3\theta^2,\theta\in(0,1).$ Why is that?

Comment: the prior depends on.. well.. your prior beliefs about $\theta$, so this is just a particular choice of $\pi(\theta)$ which apparently gives higher probability to higher values of $\theta$.

Comment: Thus in this case by any chance it is not derived from data in question?

Comment: that is correct

Comment: Interpretation and outline: You have a beta prior $\pi(\theta)$ and a geometric likelihood function $\pi(x|\theta),$ based on $x = 0.$ Use POSTERIOR $\propto$ PRIOR $\times$ LIKELIHOOD, to get a the kernel of the posterior distribution $\pi(\theta|x).$ Then identify the posterior distribution. There are several kinds of Bayes' estimates based on the posterior. From your Question, it seems you want the _mean_ of the posterior distribution. Maybe you or someone else will pursue the outline to obtain a numerical answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prior distribution $\theta \sim \mathsf{Beta}(3,1)$ with density
function $\pi(\theta) = 3\theta^2 = 3\theta^{3-1}(1-\theta)^{1-1},$ for 
$0 < \theta < 1,$  has
mean $E(\theta) = 3/(3+1) = 3/4$ and places probability 0.875 in $(.5, 1).$
You can learn more about beta distributions from your text or from the
Wikipedia article. The probability 0.875 can be obtained by integration
of the density function or from software. The computation in R statistical
software is shown below.

```
1-pbeta(.5, 3, 1)
## 0.875
```

> Thus you begin this inferential procedure with the prior information or
>   personal belief that $\theta,$ which must lie in $(0,1)$ is noticeably greater
>   than $1/2.$ All Bayesian inferences begin with a prior distribution.

The geometric likelihood function corresponding to data $x = 0$ is 
$\pi(x|\theta) = (1 - \theta)\theta^x = \pi(0|\theta) = (1-\theta).$

Following my Comment, by Bayes' Theorem, the posterior distribution is
$$\pi(\theta|x) \propto \pi(\theta) = \theta^2 \times (1 - \theta)
\propto \theta^2(1-\theta) = \theta^{3-1}(1-\theta)^{2-1},$$
where the symbol $\propto$ (read 'proportional to') recognizes that we
are using the kernels of the prior and posterior density functions
and omitting the constants, which are not necessary.

We recognize the
posterior kernel as that of $\mathsf{Beta}(3,2),$ which has mean $3/(3+2) = 0.6.$
Thus $E(\Theta|0) = 0.6.$ The central idea of Bayesian estimation is that
the information in the prior distribution and the data are combined to 
yield a posterior distribution. In this case the data $X=0$ has reduced the
estimated mean
from 0.75 to 0.6.

This easy identification of the posterior distribution is possible because
the prior distribution and the likelihood function are *conjugate* (that is
'mathematically compatible') so that the kernel of the posterior density
is easily recognized.

*Note:* A 95% Bayesian posterior interval estimate of $\Theta$ is $(.194, .932).$

```
qbeta(c(.025,.975), 3, 2)
## 0.1941204 0.9324140
```